# Compatibilty Brother DCP-J152W with Linux Elementary

Tags: printer

I recently switched from Linux Mint to Linux Elementary, but now I can not use my Brother DCP-J152W any more, is there a solution to solve this problem or should I buy a new printer that is more up to date and what is the best printer to chose?

Comment: Thanks Mr. Schulze, I will try/

Answer (score 1):

Try to download the linux (deb) drivers from [Support page](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=de&lang=de&prod=dcpj152w_us_eu_as&os=128&flang=English#SelectLanguageType-625_0_1). (I would try it with the Driver Install Tool from this mentioned support page.) Maybe you need to install a deb package manager first (`sudo apt install eddy`), but I did not try to install the printer drivers.

Then follow the install instructions on the support page:

> Step1. Download the tool.(linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz)
>
> The tool will be downloaded into the default "Download" directory. 
>   (The directory location varies depending on your Linux distribution.) 
>   e.g. /home/(LoginName)/Download
>
> Step2. Open a terminal window.
>
> Step3. Go to the directory you downloaded the file to in the last
>   step. By using the cd command.
>
> e.g. cd Downloads
>
> Step4. Enter this command to extract the downloaded file:
>
> Command: gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-*.gz
>
> e.g. `gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1.gz`
>
> Step5. Get superuser authorization with the "su" command or "sudo su"
>   command.
>
> Step6. Run the tool:
>
> Command: bash linux-brprinter-installer-*.*.*-* Brother machine name
>   e.g. `sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.1.1-1 MFC-J880DW`
>
> Step7. The driver installation will start. Follow the installation
>   screen directions.
>
> When you see the message "Will you specify the DeviceURI ?",
>
> For USB Users: Choose N(No)   For Network Users: Choose Y(Yes) and
>   DeviceURI number.
>
> The install process may take some time. Please wait until it is
>   complete.